# Low disk space on var - snaps (19.10)

Tags: snap

I have problem with space in var. The reason are snaps files, so I tried some ways to remove them, but the problem is still same. I tried to execute file, but it not work for me - https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-remove-old-snap-versions-to-free.html. Find a way to remove it with one line code:

```
snap list --all | while read snapname ver rev trk pub notes; do if [[ $notes = *disabled* ]]; then snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$rev"; fi; done
```

This remove some old snaps version but the problem is still there:

```
kunca@kunca:/var/lib/snapd/snaps$ ls -l
total 1802740
-rw------- 1 root root  30306304 фев  6 18:14 chromium-ffmpeg_15.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 149807104 май 16 10:51 code_33.snap
-rw------- 1 root root  57618432 май 16 10:49 core18_1754.snap
-rw------- 1 root root  98484224 май 16 10:49 core_9066.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 184406016 май 22 09:27 gimp_273.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 167931904 фев  6 19:48 gnome-3-28-1804_116.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 267980800 май 16 10:53 gnome-3-34-1804_33.snap
-rw------- 1 root root   2555904 май 16 10:50 gnome-calculator_748.snap
-rw------- 1 root root    282624 май 16 10:50 gnome-characters_539.snap
-rw------- 1 root root    978944 май 16 10:50 gnome-logs_100.snap
-rw------- 1 root root    135168 фев  7 00:50 gtk2-common-themes_9.snap
-rw------- 1 root root  65105920 май 16 10:50 gtk-common-themes_1506.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 273375232 май 16 10:54 kde-frameworks-5-core18_32.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 147828736 май 26 14:41 opera-developer_100.snap
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 авг 30  2019 partial
-rw------- 1 root root 119734272 май 22 09:27 signal-desktop_321.snap
-rw------- 1 root root  72372224 май 25 18:37 telegram-desktop_1634.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 207060992 фев  6 17:36 viber-mtd_17.snap
kunca@kunca:/var/lib/snapd/snaps$
```

[screen snaps space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHdAU.png)